# Find a value in a binary tree avoiding stackoverflow exception

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion

I'm trying to find a value in a binary tree and returning the node that has the value I'm looking for.

I did an algorithm that works well when the value is not in a very deep level of the tree, but when the value is in a deep position I get a `java.lang.StackOverflowError`. Here is my code:

```
class Nope {
    
    Nope left, right;
    int value;

    public Nope find(int v){
        if(v > this.value && this.right != null)
            return right.find(v);
        if(v < this.value && this.left != null)
            return left.find(v);
        if(this.value == v)
            return this;
        return null;
    }
}
```

Can any one suggest me a solution about this issue (I heard about something like tail optimization recursion) but I'm not sure of it working in Java.

Comment: Hint: the approach to avoiding deep recursion is often to use iteration instead. How could you turn your method into a loop instead?

Comment: Store your binary tree in the form of an array like for  i th position will have it's left and right child at 2*i and 2*i+1 and then you easily iterate over this array ...

Comment: So while you are taking input from the user, for a binary tree in the array and for dynamic purpose you might have to use array list

Comment: @JonSkeet  wow, nice to meet the god of this site

Comment: @zenwraight, `2*i` and `2*i+1` indices work only for a complete binary tree (binary heap for example), but for sure that doesn't cancel the ability to store a binary tree in an array.

Comment: A stack overflow is unlikely unless your tree is very deep. What's the depth that overflows ? How was the tree built ?

Comment: For an exercise, this is fine - in practice, though, there's not a real excuse to have anything but a balanced binary search tree, and then recursion would not be a concern for realistic limitations on the recursion depth. For the purposes of this exercise - you don't even really need to remember what you've seen since you never need to backtrack. A simple loop that changes the "root" node to one of the children at each step will work fine.

Comment: @DAle: There's no need for a stack in this case, as there's no need to "unwind" anything. Just a `while` loop which keeps track of which node it's currently looking at would be enough.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I was about to add the same comment but then I noticed it isn't specified the tree is balanced. If the tree is heavily unbalanced then its depth is O(n) in the number of nodes, which could be problematic. A balanced binary search tree would not have the problem, though.

Comment: @Patrick87: perfectly unbalanced trees do not arise by accident. Here I would suspect an ill-built tree with cycles.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Agreed, but this is an exercise, not an accident. Adding the first `n` integers in order to a simply implemented unbalanced binary search tree will produce a perfectly unbalanced tree.

Comment: @JonSkeet, but how? We have no information about the parent in the `Node` class.

Comment: @DAle: Why would you need information about the parent? You're only *descending* into the tree. I suggest you try doing it on paper, and work out what information you still need at any step.

Comment: @JonSkeet, oh, sorry, I've missed that this is actually a search tree. Thanks!

Comment: @Patrick87: how do you know ?

Comment: Recursive tree searches shouldn't overflow, unless you have a degenerate tree with millions of nodes. Are you sure your tree is built correctly? It seems to me you must have a loop in the tree.

Comment: @YvesDaoust It is a guess based on the assumption that (a) nobody would implement something like this himself in Java for production use, (b) if they did, they would at least make the tree balanced, and (c) in realistic use cases, they wouldn't get a stack overflow since, as you point out, odds are the tree wouldn't be badly unbalanced in the first place.

Comment: Thank you all for the valuable information you all mentioned.

Comment: Contents of this question were edited to remove claimed copyrighted content in a DMCA Takedown Request by CoderPad, Inc.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The simplest approach is to convert this into a `while` loop, which just maintains state of "the current node we're testing".

On each iteration of the loop, there are three possibilities:

- The current node has the right value, in which case you can return it
- The current node has a subnode on the correct "side", in which case you can continue iterating with that subnode as the new "current node"
- Neither of the above is the case, in which case the value isn't found and you can return null

So something like:

```
public Nope find(int v) {
    Nope current = this;
    while (current != null) {
        if (current.value == v) {
            return current;
        }
        // This will drop out of the loop naturally if there's no appropriate subnode
        current = v < current.value ? current.left : current.right;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Or with even less code, but perhaps less readably:

```
public Nope find(int v) {
    Nope current = this;
    // Keep navigating down the tree until either we've run
    // out of nodes to look at, or we've found the right value.
    while (current != null && current.value != v) {
        current = v < current.value ? current.left : current.right;
    }
    return current;
}
```

Comment: @DAle: Yup, but unfortunately I was in a tunnel with no signal, so couldn't fix it! Fixed now :)

Comment: Contents of this answer were edited to remove claimed copyrighted content in a DMCA Takedown Request by CoderPad, Inc.

Answer (score 5):

An example of your code recast as iteration:

```
class Nope {

    // keep these​​​​​​​​‌‌‌‌‌​​‌‌​​​​​​‌​‌​‌‌‌​ fields
    Nope left, right;
    int value;

    public Nope find(int v){
        Nope n = this;

        while (n != null)
        {
            if (v > n.value)
                n = n.right;
            else if (v < n.value)
                n = n.left;
            else // v == n.value
                return n;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Edit: just a note on how this works, in case it's unclear. Since you never need to remember anything about how you got to the current node, we only keep track of the root of the current subtree we need to search. At each step, we've either determined there is no subtree left to search (first condition), there might be a subtree to the left or right (middle two conditions), or that we have actually found the value at the root of the current subtree (last condition). We keep looking until we run out of subtrees (while condition) and, if we do run out, we know the value isn't in the tree and we return null.

Edit: As pointed out in the comments, the use of consecutive `if`s is a problem. I have updated the code to use if/else if/else.

Comment: One note on this - the node that you're testing against can change within the iteration of the loop. A single iteration could go to the right, then to that node's left, then find the result! I think it's simpler to do one "step" per iteration, as per my answer. This would still work, I just think it's slightly less clear.

Comment: @JonSkeet Good point, I hadn't considered that. I suppose this is still correct as rendered. I'll add a node that using if/else if/else would make it a little clearer that one iteration of the `while` loop is one comparison of the value to the root's value.

Comment: @JonSkeet Actually, I realized that breaks the code. I have updated to use if/else if/else. The problem arises if you run out of subtrees within one iteration of the old code; then you get NPE.

Comment: True, hadn't thought about that :)

Answer (score 0):

Tree searches are used to avoid iterating over large arrays.

The weakness of the tree approach is when the node values are ordered. As the tree is loaded, every node goes to the left or right, causing a lot of recursion. Having said that, stack overflow takes a lot of recursion.

You can either hash the values, which will tend to balance the tree, or you can enhance your tree building algorithm to balance the tree if a particular branch gets too long.

Having said that, you should also look at how many nodes are in your tree that there are enough to cause a stack overflow. You may have a bug in your code that is not shown here.

Comment: Nice touch with the hashing.

Comment: Hashing is not a terrible idea, as ideas go, but it doesn't provide any guarantees you'll end up with a balanced tree. Much better, in my humble opinion, to go ahead and use AVL or red-black trees and get some provable, deterministic behavior with worst-case bounds lower than the naïve unbalanced implementation.

Comment: If you're going to hash the values then you should (except in rare cases) use a hash table.  Binary search trees are used when you need to find values closest to a given value or within a range, and hashing the values breaks this kind of search.

Comment: I agree with the above. I assumed that this was an exercise, not for real use.

Answer (score -2):

You can use `Xss` JVM argument to increase the memory allocated to the thread stack. This will allow you to have a larger method call stack.

> -**Xsssize**
>
> Sets the thread stack size (in bytes). Append the letter k or K to indicate KB, m or M to indicate MB, g or G to indicate GB. The
> default value depends on virtual memory.
>
> The following examples set the thread stack size to 1024 KB in
> different units:
>
> -Xss1m
>
> -Xss1024k
>
> -Xss1048576

Ref: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html

Otherwise you can always convert the recursion to the a loop, that would mean you would have to manage the call stack of the method (arguments and return values) yourself in a stack, that can become messy.

**Note:** For search operation there's no need for a stack as mentioned by Jon Skeet. Search doesn't need to keep track of where it's been. However for backtracking a reference to parent would be required, and we will have to make sure that we always start with left child.

Comment: There's no need to use a stack here. Just a while loop which keeps track of the current node you're looking at is fine: on each iteration, you've either a) found the value; b) found a subnode to look at, or c) determined that the value isn't present.

Comment: You're right, even if backtracking is required it can be done by having a reference to the parent.

Comment: Downvoter, other than the backtracking comment what exactly is your issue with the answer given here?